# Java to convert Hexidecimal to Signed 8-Bit Code

Tags: java, hex, 8-bit

I need to convert Hexideciamal numbers represented as a String to a Signed 8-Bit String.

**For Example: Given this Code Snippet:**

```
String hexideciaml = new String("50  4b e0  e7");
String signed8Bit = convertHexToSigned8Bit(hexideciaml);
System.out.print(signed8Bit);
```

**The Output should be:**
"80 75 -32 -25"

So I pretty much want to implement part of this website in Java. https://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-decimal-hexadecimal-converter.html

**Update:** Solution needs to be for JRE6 with no other Jars.

Comment: Why would the "50" remain unhexified?  I'd expect the output to be "80 75 -32 -25"

Comment: Parse the `String` using space as a delimiter. Then convert each value to an `Integer` with a radix of 16 via `Integer.parseInt(String, int)`. Cast that value to `byte` to convert it to a signed value.

Comment: You are correct @Reimeus. Updating question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 1.8 (stream)

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class HexToDec {

    public static String convertHexToSigned8Bit(String hex) {
        return Arrays
                .stream(hex.split(" +"))
                .map(s -> "" + (byte) Integer.parseInt(s, 16))
                .reduce((s, s2) -> s + " " + s2)
                .get();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hexidecimal = "50  4b e0  e7";
        String signed8Bit = convertHexToSigned8Bit(hexidecimal);
        System.out.print(signed8Bit);
    }

}
```

Java <1.8

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class HexToDec {

    public static String convertHexToSigned8Bit(String hex) {
        String[] tokens = hex.split(" +");
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length - 1; i++) { //append all except last
            result.append((byte) Integer.parseInt(tokens[i], 16)).append(" ");
        }
        if (tokens.length > 1) //if more than 1 item in array, add last one
            result.append((byte) Integer.parseInt(tokens[tokens.length - 1], 16));
        return result.toString();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hexidecimal = "50  4b e0  e7";
        String signed8Bit = convertHexToSigned8Bit(hexidecimal);
        System.out.print(signed8Bit);
    }

}
```

Output is: 80 75 -32 -25

Comment: Hmm does not seem to compile. I get this error `The method stream(String[]) is undefined for the type Arrays`, solution needs to be for JRE6. Also where is `s2` initialized?

Comment: Ofc it won't compile for JRE6. I used streams, which are present since JRE8. Wait a sec, I will rewrite it for JRE6

Comment: Works perfectly with JRE 6. I suggest you update your answer with both solutions, 1 for Jre6 and 1 for Jre8. Then I will except your answer. Thank you!